# Multi Class Classification on large dataset with over 600 classes

Tags: machine-learning, svm, logistic-regression, multiclass-classification, word2vec

I'm trying to train a text data for multi class classification which comprises of 1 Million rows. After cleaning the data, I'm using a sparse matrix of Word2Vec features (Feature size is 300)

The data which I have is 1. ID 2. Dictionary 3. Label

Dictionary size varies from 10 keys to 900 keys

Steps I followed on Dictionary columns are:

Converted Dictionary to String
Getting only good tokens from the string
Removing Stopwords
Stemming of words
Word2Vec Model training with feature size 300.
Word2Vec feaure generation
Label Encoding
Converting Feature Vectors to Numpy Array
Converting Numpy Array to Sparse Matrix of (1114220, 300)
Tried OneVsRest model for training
onevsrest = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(probability=True) , n_jobs=-1)

onevsrest.fit(sparse_matrix , df.labels)

I was running this model for nearly two days and it got killed automatically

I also tried Logistic Regression

lr = LogisticRegression(penalty ='l1' , C=1 ,dual=False , solver='saga' , n_jobs=-1)

lr.fit(sparse_matrix , df.labels)

Still I faced the same issue ( Model keeps training for 2 days and gets killed)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any better way to do this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I have seen SVM perform well with Text Classification tasks. Why don't you first try with taking TF-IDF in place of Word2vec.
Let's say you have a sentence D1 with terms T1,T2 and T3. Represent it as TF-IDF first and classify. This link might help https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/
Then you will know if the problem is with memory issues or your word2vec approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try chi-square or enthropy based classification, i.e. anything non-linear. They are more robust, precise and humanly relevant than linear models (regressions or SVM).
You can also clusterize your base of documents and/or features (words, terms, vectors).
Another idea is to go through topic discovery so you can identify closely related in significance manner terms.